# Cannot save ArrayList of Uri in a file: NotSerializableException

Tags: android, parcelable

I must save an ArrayList of Ury so I use the code

```
public static void saveUriList(ArrayList<Uri> myUriList) {
        if (storageAvailable()) {
            try {
                FileOutputStream uriListSaved = new FileOutputStream(
                        baseDir + File.separator + filename);
                ObjectOutputStream uriList = new ObjectOutputStream(
                        uriListSaved);
                uriList.writeObject(myUriList);
                uriList.close();
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace(); 
            }
        }

    }
```

This code structure works fine for custom object that implements serializable but with Uri objects returns this Exception

```
10-18 21:06:40.169: W/System.err(11957): java.io.WriteAbortedException: Read an exception; java.io.NotSerializableException: android.net.Uri$StringUri
10-18 21:06:40.169: W/System.err(11957):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:933)
10-18 21:06:40.169: W/System.err(11957):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2262)
10-18 21:06:40.169: W/System.err(11957):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2217)
10-18 21:06:40.169: W/System.err(11957):    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:665)
10-18 21:06:40.169: W/System.err(11957):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-18 21:06:40.169: W/System.err(11957):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-18 21:06:40.169: W/System.err(11957):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1520)
10-18 21:06:40.169: W/System.err(11957):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1443)
10-18 21:06:40.169: W/System.err(11957):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2112)
10-18 21:06:40.169: W/System.err(11957):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:916)
10-18 21:06:40.169: W/System.err(11957):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2262)
10-18 21:06:40.169: W/System.err(11957):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2217)
10-18 21:06:40.169: W/System.err(11957):    at it.myApp.testApp.utility.FileArchiveManager.loadUriList(FileArchiveManager.java:158)
10-18 21:06:40.169: W/System.err(11957):    at it.myApp.testApp.MyClass.onCreate(MyClass.java:107)
10-18 21:06:40.169: W/System.err(11957):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-18 21:06:40.169: W/System.err(11957):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
10-18 21:06:40.169: W/System.err(11957):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
10-18 21:06:40.169: W/System.err(11957):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-18 21:06:40.169: W/System.err(11957):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
10-18 21:06:40.169: W/System.err(11957):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-18 21:06:40.169: W/System.err(11957):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-18 21:06:40.169: W/System.err(11957):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
10-18 21:06:40.179: W/System.err(11957):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-18 21:06:40.179: W/System.err(11957):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-18 21:06:40.179: W/System.err(11957):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
10-18 21:06:40.179: W/System.err(11957):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
10-18 21:06:40.179: W/System.err(11957):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-18 21:06:40.179: W/System.err(11957): Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.net.Uri$StringUri
10-18 21:06:40.179: W/System.err(11957):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1535)
10-18 21:06:40.179: W/System.err(11957):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
10-18 21:06:40.179: W/System.err(11957):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
10-18 21:06:40.179: W/System.err(11957):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
10-18 21:06:40.179: W/System.err(11957):    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:651)
10-18 21:06:40.179: W/System.err(11957):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-18 21:06:40.179: W/System.err(11957):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-18 21:06:40.179: W/System.err(11957):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1219)
10-18 21:06:40.179: W/System.err(11957):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
10-18 21:06:40.179: W/System.err(11957):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
10-18 21:06:40.179: W/System.err(11957):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
10-18 21:06:40.179: W/System.err(11957):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
10-18 21:06:40.179: W/System.err(11957):    at it.myApp.testApp.utility.FileArchiveManager.salvaListaPathImmagini(FileArchiveManager.java:127)
10-18 21:06:40.179: W/System.err(11957):    at it.myApp.testApp.LoadImage.onActivityResult(LoadImage.java:120)
10-18 21:06:40.179: W/System.err(11957):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
10-18 21:06:40.179: W/System.err(11957):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
10-18 21:06:40.179: W/System.err(11957):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2578)
10-18 21:06:40.179: W/System.err(11957):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-18 21:06:40.179: W/System.err(11957):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:965)
10-18 21:06:40.189: W/System.err(11957):    ... 8 more
```

I suppose that this happen because Uri doesn't implements Serializable....

How could I fix this problem? Must I create a custom Uri Object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you already noticed, Uri does not implement Serializable, see the reference [android.net.Uri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html). 
How about storing your uris as Strings when writing your file, and converting them back to uris using `Uri.parse()` when reading the file?

Comment: mmmm... I hope in another solution because I should change a lot of methods changing from Uri to String in this Object.

Comment: You don't need to change any methods. Inside your saveUriList method you create a ArrayList<String>() list and add all uris from your ArrayList<Uri>() to this list. When reading the file, e.g. loadUriList, you do it vice versa. Read the object --> ArrayList<String>(), create a ArrayList<Uri>() list and parse all strings to uris, adding them to the list.

Answer (score 3):

when saving

```
String str = myUri.toString();
```

and when loading

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse(str);
```